# An empty snapshotView on iPhone 7/7plus

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, ios10

My first question here:)  Recently I update my Xcode to 8, and the `resizableSnapshotView` method doesn't work properly on some simulators. The snapshotView works well on all testing devices with iOS9/10 and simulators under iPhone6s, but it is empty on iPhone7/7p simulators. I think 7/7p may need some authorities for accessing snapshot, but I have no idea what they are.

```
let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as! CalendarCell     
var topFrame = cell.frame
topFrame.origin.y = tableView.contentOffset.y
topFrame.size.height -= tableView.contentOffset.y
topSnapshotView = tableView.resizableSnapshotView(from: topFrame, afterScreenUpdates: false, withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero)
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same, good to hear it only happens on Simulators.

Comment: Exactly the same problem, however I haven't tested this on real devices yet

Comment: To Alf. Unfortunately, I don't have a real device and I'm not sure whether this happens on real devices.

Comment: Still a problem in Xcode 8.1/iOS 10.1 Beta 1.

Comment: Could not reproduce it on a iPhone 7 device with iOS 10.0, so still hope this is a simulator only issue. @LYM did you file a radar with Apple?

Comment: I've just reported to Apple, hope they fix it soon.@Alf

Comment: Cool, would be great if you could update this issue here once you hear any news!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following UIView extension to create a snapshot using CoreGraphics.

I can confirm this works on iPhone 7 simulator.

```
public extension UIView {

    public func snapshotImage() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, 0)
        drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
        let snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return snapshotImage
    }

    public func snapshotView() -> UIView? {
        if let snapshotImage = snapshotImage() {
            return UIImageView(image: snapshotImage)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. However, my main matter is to use `resizableSnapshotView` this function. I have tried some time to rewrite it with your code but failed. Could you show me how to clip the snapshotView with a frame.

Comment: This does not work. It produces the same results for me as the old methods. Tried it with Xcode 8 and iPhone 7/7+ simulator.

Comment: Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work after I updating to Xcode 8.1 either.

Answer (score 0):

Works in:

- *Version 8.1 (8B62)*
- *Simulator Version 10.0 (SimulatorApp-700.14*

**Swift 3**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func snapshotView() -> UIView? {
        guard let image = snapshotImage() else { return nil }
        return UIImageView(image: image)
    }

    func snapshotImage() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, contentScaleFactor)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }

        drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)

        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}
```