# Swift 3 / Why does the snapshot from snapshotView appears blank in iPhone 7 Plus Simulator?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the following code to create a custom Menu transition. I have spent the last two hours trying to figure out, why the snapshot appears blank (using the iPhone 7 Plus simulator only). But when I wanted to create a video to make it into a gif for this thread, *it worked on my iPhone 6S Plus*.

**Update:** Works on iPhone 6S Simulator as well. But still not in 7 Plus.

```
import UIKit

class PresentMenuAnimator : NSObject {
}

extension PresentMenuAnimator : UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.6
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)
        let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        containerView.insertSubview((toVC?.view)!, belowSubview: (fromVC?.view)!)

        // replace main view with snapshot
        let snapshot = fromVC?.view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
        snapshot?.tag = MenuHelper.snapshotNumber
        snapshot?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        snapshot?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        containerView.insertSubview(snapshot!, aboveSubview: (toVC?.view)!)
        fromVC?.view.isHidden = true

        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext),
            animations: {
                snapshot!.center.x += UIScreen.main.bounds.width * MenuHelper.menuWidth
            },
            completion: { _ in
                fromVC?.view.isHidden = false
                transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

**iPhone 6S Plus (physical device) iOS 10**

[image]

**iPhone 7 Plus (simulator) iOS 10**

[image]

[image]

Why is the snapshot on the simulator blank?

[GitHub test project](https://github.com/davidseek/InteractiveSlideOutMenu)

Comment: I've tried running the project and it's working fine for me on 6s simulator (14A345)

Comment: iPhone 7 Plus sim? 14A345

Comment: works with 6s simulator, too. just tried. but 7 plus, not

Comment: [This thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63438) suggests that this only happens in the simulator, not on real iPhone 7 devices.

Comment: Curious about the case too. Have you found the reason?

Comment: @Startry unfortunately not. Just, that it does only happen in Simulator

Comment: It does happen in my real device, iPhone 6S iOS 13...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alternative solution,

Add this `UIView` extension,

```
public extension UIView {
    public func snapshotImage() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, 0)
        drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
        let snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return snapshotImage
    }

    public func snapshotView() -> UIView? {
        if let snapshotImage = snapshotImage() {
            return UIImageView(image: snapshotImage)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Update your following code,

```
let snapshot = fromVC?.view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
```

with,

```
let snapshot = fromVC?.view.snapshotView()
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39636687/3411787)

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question of why snapshotview(afterScreeUpdates:) isn't working, only provides an alternative solution. Do you have any idea why the method isn't working? I've run into the same issue

Comment: Yep.. also same issue... and the drawing into an image is pretty slow... so I also like to know what the problem is...

Comment: Thanks @Zaid, but do you know why it is so different from snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates:) ??? It'd be great to know more about it

Comment: Is there any update as to why this happens? I cannot find anything on why this method might return nil

Comment: Sorry folks,I don't know reason for original question, it's just alternative solution as written on top.